# Google charts - Main title and axis size

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to change the font size for the main title and axis titles but I cannot with this code:

```
  var options = {
    title: 'Ratio de supervivencia de aerolíneas europeas',
    chartArea:{
         top: 20,
         bottom: 50,
         height: '75%'
    },
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    hAxis: {title: 'Nº total de aerolíneas históricas', titleFontSize: 24},
    vAxis: {title: 'Ratio de supervivencia', format: 'percent', maxValue: 0.7, titleFontSize: 24},
    bubble: {textStyle: {fontSize: 11}}
  };
```

[image]

Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance & regards,
Luis

Answer (score 0):

there is *no* option for --> `titleFontSize`

instead, use the option for --> `titleTextStyle`

e.g.

```
hAxis: {
  titleTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 24
  }
}
```

see [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart#configuration-options) for more...